# duplicate records in table in SQL with two same column values and one different value

Tags: mysql, sql

I am having three fields and I want to find out unique records with same `c3` and `c1` and different `c2`.

My `c1`, `c2` and `c3` are column names. I need to find out with in the same `c1` and `c3` where is `c2` different.

eg.

```
+-----+------+--------+
| c1  |  c2  |   c3   |
+-----+------+--------+
| A10 | Z10  | text1  |
| A10 | Z10  | text1  |
| A10 | Z40  | text2  |
| A10 | Z50  | text1  |
| A20 | Z100 | text1  |
| A20 | Z200 | text1  |
| A50 | Z10  | text1  |
| A60 | Z10  | text1  |
| A60 | Z10  | text1  |
+-----+------+--------+
```

My output reqd is from `A10` group as `C3` is duplicated

so I need:

```
+-----+-----+-------+
| c1  | c2  |  c3   |
+-----+-----+-------+
| A10 | Z10 | text1 |
| A10 | Z50 | text1 |
+-----+-----+-------+
```

from `A20` group both should appear as `C3` is same and `C2` is different.

```
+-----+------+-------+
| c1  |  c2  |  c3   |
+-----+------+-------+
| A20 | Z100 | text1 |
| A20 | Z200 | text1 |
+-----+------+-------+
```

and from A50 and A60 nothing should in the output as either they are unique or duplicated.

Final output is :

```
+-----+------+-------+
| c1  |  c2  |  c3   |
+-----+------+-------+
| A10 | Z10  | text1 |
| A10 | Z50  | text1 |
| A20 | Z100 | text1 |
| A20 | Z200 | text1 |
+-----+------+-------+
```

I tried to find out duplicate C3 and applied various joins but not able to get the required results.

Comment: Please check again and share with us do you use MySQL or SQLServer or maybe Postgresql? There can be only one ...

Comment: See https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-a-minimal-reproducible-example-for-a-very-simple-sql-query

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This should give you what you need:

```
with t as
(
    select
        c1,
        c3,
        count(distinct c2) as n
    from
        YourTable
    group by
        c1,
        c3
    having
        count(distinct c2) > 1
)

select distinct
    YourTable.c1,
    YourTable.c2,
    YourTable.c3
from
    YourTable
inner join
    t
on
    YourTable.c1 = t.c1
    and YourTable.c3 = t.c3
```

Answer (score 0):

I think the simplest way to do this uses `exists`:

```
select distinct c1, c2, c3
from t
where exists (select 1
              from t t2
              where t2.c1 = t.c1 and t2.c3 = t.c2 and
                    t2.c2 <> t.c2
             );
```

With an index on `(c1, c3, c2)`, I would also expect this to have the best performance (although it would be interesting if a test showed that this is not the case).